# MediaPlayer error (1, -1004) Why?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

iam playing a video from URL and its working fine but some times

the Log gives

```
MediaPlayer  error (1, -1004) 
MediaPlayer  Error (1, -1004)
```

and some times its Starting a dialog that says the media player cannot play this video 
for the same URL |
so **Why this happening , what is the meaning of this error and how to solve it ?**

this is my code

```
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(mActivity);

    mediaController.setAnchorView(VideoViewplayer);
    VideoViewplayer.setMediaController(mediaController);
    VideoViewplayer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("a URL" + ".mp4"));
    VideoViewplayer.start();
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939243/video-player-does-not-play-the-video-every-time

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: you can try webview

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Uri video = Uri.parse(url);
MediaController  mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(VideoViewplayer);
VideoViewplayer.requestFocus();
VideoViewplayer.setMediaController(mediaController);
VideoViewplayer.setVideoURI(video);

VideoViewplayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0)
    {
        VideoViewplayer.start();
    }
});
```